# Display data from some columns from multiple tables in oracle not working

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, union-all

I have multiple tables from which I want to just show data of 2-3 columns from each tables. So I tried using like below

```
SELECT RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_NAME, RJ_R4G_STATE_NAME, RJ_SITE_NAME FROM ne.mv_structure@FACID147
union all
select model_name,serial_no from solar_equipment
union all
select model_name from solar_plugin;
```

But getting error as

> ORA-01789: query block has incorrect number of result columns

Comment: Please share sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `UNION` them, then all `SELECT` statements must have the same number of columns (that would be `3` in your case), and they must match in **datatype**.

For example:

```
select rj_maintenance_zone_name, rj_r4g_state_name, rj_site_name
from ne.mv_structure@FACID147
UNION ALL
select null                    , model_name       , to_char(serial_no)
from solar_equipment
UNION ALL
select null                    , model_name       , null
from solar_plugin
```

Comment: i am not getting model name column, any other way to achieve this,? I want to only select columns from the tables